# Disable Junk Email settings via GPO

Tags: group-policy, outlook, outlook-2010

I’m looking to disable the Junk Email folder within outlook 2007 and 2010, Clients are Mainly XP with some Win 7 (32/64bit), and this is on a Windows 2008 domain. I thought the best way to do this would be via GPO. The GPO is applying fine and is applying all other settings but not the Outlook part.

I have tried to use the following registry keys

```
   Outlook 2007: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\12.0\outlook
    Outlook 2010: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\14.0\outlook  (<--- Create if path doesn't exist)

    Add the Key:
    dWord (32bit Value): DisableAntiSpam
    Value: 1 (Hex)  ---  1 Disables JunkMail and 0 Enables it
```

But this isn’t applying and the outlook client is still trying to filter the junk emails.

Footnote. I am trying to disable this as spam is now being processed in the cloud and at the perimeter of the network and it is only internal mail that is being wrongly classified (mainly due to bulk sending from our ERP system)

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, but just the opposite which should work as long as all your users go through exchange.

What we can do is set the spam confidence for ALL mail to 0 which will effectively disable the Junk Mail. This should be way quicker then GPO as well.

If you Open Exchange
Go to Organizational Configuration
Go to Hub Transport
Go to the Transport Rules Tab then create a new Rule.
From here you can set the policy of which emails you want, or even set a rule to encompass all emails. 
The important part is you set the Spam confidence to 0. This will prevent items from going to the Junk mail folder.